# What happens during Windows refreshing the icons on your desktop?

Tags: windows

I have many icons on my desktop. From time to time the symbols change from their normal one into some kind of "white standard icon" and than suddenly turning back to the normal icons, slowly, one by one ...
When i refresh it, by pressing F5, it works instantly.

What's that? Why does this happen? Why takes it so long and slows down my machine dramatically during this process?

I have noticed that on my Vista system and on my laptop with XP System.

Comment: As of Dec 2009, this question has an accepted answer, but doesn't really have an answer... only speculation as to what is going on.
Does anyone KNOW what is happening and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> From time to time the symbols change
>   from their normal one into some kind
>   of "white standard icon" and than
>   suddenly turning back to the normal
>   icons, slowly, one by one ...

i suppose Windows is rebuilding the Icon Cache while when you press F5 it is only reloading the layout from cache.

Comment: do you know why this process is so slow and stalls most of the system?

Comment: not really, not an 'expert on desktop icons' (i have NONE on my desktop :) but you may check your event log for errors.